# How to stream data from a USB device using LIBUSB and Ruby on Mac/OSX?

Tags: ruby, macos, libusb

I am interested in streaming data from a USB device (in this case, a USB scale, but it could be a keyboard or any other device).  All of the tutorials and documentation I've read gets me this far:

```
require "libusb"
require 'usb'  # this is the ruby-usb gem

d = USB.devices.last # note, I am sure that this is the correct device
i = d.interfaces.last
e = i.endpoints.last
h = d.open
```

However this is as far as I get.  When I attempt to use

```
h.usb_claim_interface
```

even as root, I get:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - usb_claim_interface
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible to simply open a file at /dev/something and tail it instead?  Any feedback or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the last would be a workable solution too. A USB device should be mounted in /dev. Grab a list of the devices prior to plugging it in, then plug it in and see if anything new shows up in the directory, or open a Finder window and watch to see what appears.

Comment: I am struggling with the same thing. I have a usb-controller which I would love to be able to get the input from.

Comment: have you succeeded? i'm interested in the same topic and woud be happy to get some hints!